# Raspbian: dpkg hangs during raspberrypi-kernel package upgrade

Tags: raspbian, kernel, apt, update, dpkg

while doing an apt upgrade on my Raspberry Pi 4 (Raspbian 10 - Buster), *dpkg* was interrupted during setup of the `raspberrypi-kernel` package:

```
raspberrypi-kernel (1.20190819-1) wird eingerichtet ...
»Umleitung von /boot/bcm2708-rpi-b-plus.dtb zu /usr/share/rpikernelhack/bcm2708-rpi-b-plus.dtb durch rpikernelhack« wird entfernt
```

which probably translates to

```
Set up raspberrypi-kernel (1.20190819-1) ...
»Diversion of /boot/bcm2708-rpi-b-plus.dtb to /usr/share/rpikernelhack/bcm2708-rpi-b-plus.dtb by rpikernelhack« will be removed
```

This process will hang forever (over night in my case). When I restart apt upgrade, the well known hint to use *dpkg --configure -a* will appear:

```
xxxxx@yyyyyyy:$sudo apt upgrade
[sudo] Passwort für xxxxx:
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

Executing *dpkg --configure -a*, will also hang forever and even cannot be interrupted using `CTRL-C`. I'll have to log into another session in order to explicitly kill *dpkg*.
On top of not being able to finish the kernel upgrade (which leaves me in a pretty unpleasant situation), the system load in *top* will increase with every trial, without any visible CPU- or I/O-intense processes. The only way I was able to reboot,  was connecting the SD-Card to another Raspbian 10 device and copying all the missing files from that device's /boot-Directory to my non-working device's /boot-directory.

I checked the SD-card on my computer - it seems perfectly ok.

Any ideas how to solve this? Since I've put quite some effort into this system during the last months, setting it up from scratch would be the ultima ratio.

Comment: Please don't give additional information in comments. Instead edit the question and add it there.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @Ingo. I wasn't able to close the question so this seemed appropriate to me.

Comment: If you have found the solution so please make an answer. Two days later you can accept your own answer. This will finish the whole question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out, that the reason for the hanging dpkg process was a hanging call to `sync` in two post-installation-scripts: `raspberrypi-kernel.postinst` and `raspberrypi-bootloader.postinst`, both located at `/var/lib/dpkg/info/`. After remounting root-fs using the `sync` option (`mount -o remount,sync,rw,noatime /`) and commenting out every call of `sync` in both scripts, I managed to get the new kernel installed and thus, finally be able to reboot again which finally also fixed the weird I/O problems causing `sync` to hang.

Still not sure, why `sync` didn't work before, but this method solved the situation.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.